# Pasting text with VBA results in automatic "Wrap Text". Why?

Tags: excel, vba

When I copy a long text and paste it, the formatting of the narrow cell changes to "Wrap Text".
Why? What to do about it (except changing the formatting after pasting)?

[image]

[image]

```
Sub CopyText()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowCopy As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Copytest")
    
    With ws
        LastRowCopy = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                    
        'copy
        For i = 3 To LastRowCopy
            .Cells(i, "E") = .Cells(i, "B")
        Next i

    End With
    
End Sub
```

When I copy the text from Excel to Notepad it looks like this:

[image]

If i insert one cell in Microsoft Word, it adds 12 points of spacing after the text to the new line.

So something is wrong with this text, I can't figure out what.

When I copy one text in the formula bar, paste it in the column B and run the code, there is no wrapping of the text.

Comment: Please do not include links to external files in your question.

Comment: `Clear` clears contents *and* formatting (such as the WrapText setting), so clear first, and then set `WrapText = False`

Comment: @TimWilliams I deleted that part, because it not really had to do with the question.

Comment: @braX Why not include files? It is extrem easy for people who want to help. I wished all questioner would include a file. Just pictures and words makes it much more difficult to help. Even in my answers I mostly attach a file with the solution.

Comment: Try Cell.Value instead of just Cell.

Comment: @braX Why not include files? It is extrem easy for people who want to help. I wished all questioner would include a file. Just pictures and words makes it much more difficult to help. Even in my answers I mostly attach a file with the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found it.
There where two invisible charakters in some cells.
Char(10) and Char(13)
Linebreakes
both can be removed with

```
=clean(B3)
```

or

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B3;CHAR(10);"")
=SUBSTITUTE(B3;CHAR(13);"")
```

I found the charakter so
=CODE(RIGHT(B3;1))

Also with =Len(B3) one can see the amount of charakters, even if invisible